# Comparing multiplication-tables in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to compare two ways of printing a multiplication table, and even though they print identical strings when i printf "%s" mulTable n and printf "%s" loopMulTable n, they dont seem to be the same thing when comparing them, as it prints false for every comparison in the last function. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
let a = "      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
 1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
 2    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
 3    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
 4    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40
 5    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
 6    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60
 7    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70
 8    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80
 9    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90
10   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100"

let mulTable n =
    a.[0..(n*54)+51]


let loopMulTable n = 
    let mutable returnString = ""
    returnString <- returnString + (sprintf  "  ")
    for i in 1..10 do
        returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "%5d" i)
    for x in 1..n do
        returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "\n")
        returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "%2d" x)
        for y in 1..10 do
            returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "%5d" (x*y))
    returnString

let o = "n:"
let u = "boolean value:"

let chooseN n =
    printfn "%5s %19s" o u
    for n in 1..n do
        printfn "%4d %15b" n ((loopMulTable n)=(mulTable n))


chooseN 5
```

Might i add that i am a beginner in programming and especially in F#, so there might be other flaws though they're not the problem that i'm looking to solve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test for equality is most likely failing because this line is appending a newline rather than a carriage-return-newline combination.

```fsharp
returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "\n")
```

If you are on a Windows machine, the line breaks in your source code will most likely include the carriage return character. Change it to the following and it should compare just fine:

```fsharp
returnString <- returnString + (sprintf "\r\n")
```